# Ada: pragma Pure / Remote_Types and system types

Tags: ada, pragma

I'm writing an Ada application that needs to be distributed, and I'm trying to use the DSA to do it, but I'm finding big limitations in what is "allowed" to be "withed" and what isn't.

I won't post sourcecode, since it's quite complex and this is a generic question anyway, I just wanted some pointers on what I'm not understanding correctly, so please bear with me and correct me if I'm wrong.

So my problem is this: I want to mark a procedure with the `pragma Remote_Call_Interface` so it can be called remotely. However as soon as I add the pragma compilation breaks due to the fact that the procedure is including other packages in my project that are not categorized as either `Pure` or `Remote_Types`.

So I try to mark the packages I need as either `Pure` or `Remote_Types` (dpeending wether they have state or not) but this in turn breaks compilation even further, since it turns out that you can't use even basic system types in a Pure/Remote_Types package, for example: you can't use `Vector`s, you can't use `Unbounded_String`s, you can't use `Map`s, etc... the whole program falls to pieces since I can't use the data structures I used to build it anymore!

Is there a way around this? Or if I want to distribute my application I must strictly limit myself to the most basic types like Integers and booleans and little else?? I don't understand if I'm hitting against a limitation of the language or if I'm just doing it incorrectly (unfortunately the tutorials I found on DSA are all very vague, incidentally if anyone has some good ones feel free to link them!)

**EDIT:** after ajb's answer let me specify what is annoying me in particular: in the package I want to mark with `pragma Remote_Call_Interface` I'm trying to "with" some packages that are not pure/remote_types, however it only uses the types in those packages **locally**, it does **not** contain any procedures that accept such types as parameters, nor functions that return such types. This is what bothers me: since those types would not have to "travel" over the network, why can't I with them? I'm only using them locally... I don't understand this, and that is why I was trying to make those types Pure/Remote_Types, but now that I've read ajb's explanation (ie: Remote_Types is used so that objects of those types can travel over the network) I'm even more confused about why I can't use them if I only use them locally.

Comment: In response to your edit, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert on Ada distributed programming, but here's what I do know (or think I know):

The Annotated Ada Reference Manual, Section [E.2.3](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12aarm/html/AA-E-2-3.html) says, "The restrictions governing a remote call interface library unit are intended to ensure that the values of the actual parameters in a remote call can be meaningfully sent between two active partitions."  For example, if a record type has a field that's an access type, you can't send it from one partition to another blindly, because the called partition won't be able to access the memory that the pointer points to.  (`Unbounded_String`, `Map`, and `Vector` are implemented using access types as part of the internals.)  All types used as parameters or return types must support "external streaming", meaning there has to be a way for the type to be converted to and from a stream of bytes so that the parameter value can be transmitted over a socket.  If you have a record with an access type, but you provide `'Read` and `'Write` attributes so that the type can be written to and read from a byte stream without any actual pointers being transmitted, then you can put your record type in a `Remote_Types` package.

I'm not sure exactly what your problem is: are there certain types you want to *pass* as a parameter to a remote call but can't; or are there types that you want to use only in the rest of your application, but are getting in the way?

If it's the second one, then I think the solution is to restructure your packages so that all the "remote types" are separate from the non-remote types.

However, if you're really looking to pass an `Unbounded_String`, `Map`, or `Vector` from one partition to another in a remote call, it's trickier.  `Unbounded_String` really should support external streaming, and there was a proposal to make `Unbounded_String` a `Remote_Types` package (see [AI05-0204](http://www.ada-auth.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/ai05s/ai05-0204-1.txt?rev=1.3)), but it wasn't acted on--I don't know why.  `Map` and `Vector` would be bigger problems, though, since they are generic packages that have to work on any type, including those that don't support external streaming.  In any case, those types aren't set up to be automatically converted to or from bytes to be passed over a socket.

But I think you could make it work like this:

```
private with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
package Remote_Types_Package is
    pragma Remote_Types;
    type My_Unbounded_String is private;
private
    type My_Unbounded_String is record
        S : Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String;
    end record;
end Remote_Types_Package;
```

The `Unbounded_String` package must be withed with `private with`; see E.2.2(6).  You'll need to provide a function to create the `My_Unbounded_String`, and you'll need to provide stream read and write routines for `My_Unbounded_String`, and define `'Read` and `'Write` for the type.  You should be able to write the `Read` and `Write` attributes by using the `Read` and `Write` attributes for the `Unbounded_String`.  Something similar should be doable if you want to use a `Vector` as a remote call parameter, although you may have to do more work to marshal/unmarshal the type yourself.

Once again, I have not tried this, and it's possible there are some hitches in this solution.

**EDIT:** Since it now looks like the question is the simpler one--i.e. you have some types that are *not* going to be passed between partitions getting in the way--the solution should be simpler.  Any types that you define that are going to be communicated between partitions need to be in a `Remote_Types` package, say `P1`.  Other types should be in a different package, say `P2` (or multiple packages).  If types in `P1` depend on types in `P2`, you can still get this to work by having `P1` say `private with P2;`, and making sure you have the marshalling and unmarshalling procedures you need.  If you run into difficulties, I'd encourage you to ask a new question here.

I don't know why the language required all such types to be quarantined in a `Remote_Types` package, instead of just saying that any type used in a `Remote_Call_Interface` package has to have only parts that can be streamed.  There may have been some implementation issues.  Any code that exists for a `Remote_Types` package has to be in programs in both partitions, perhaps, and this may have been an attempt to limit the type of code that would have to be linked into multiple partitions.  But I'm just guessing.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, after reading it I edited my question to (hopefully) specify the problem better.

Comment: Unfortunately no, using private with still doesn't seem to work, the compiler still says "cannot depend on "P2" (Wrong Categorization)"

Comment: EDIT: while "private with" doesn't work, "limited with" seems to work. I still have to do a bit of trickery since using limited with limits you to access types but I can manage, using an anonymous  pointer in the ADS file and doing a proper "with" in the ADB file (the withing problem only affects the header file). Will mark as answered since it pointed me in the right direction, thanks

Comment: @Master_T "Wrong categorization" might be because the package still has to be preelaborated (E.2.3(8)), which might mean you need a `Preelaborate` pragma on `P2`.

Comment: That would be useful, but it seems pragma Preelaborate is itself picky on what it allows you to with, if I use it I can't use some of the basic language packages, for example "Ada.Text_IO"

Comment: @Master_T Which means maybe you have to separate even further into packages, putting all the stuff that can be preelaborated in one package, and the rest of the stuff ... I can see how this can get really annoying.  Is there anywhere where you can post your code (pastebin, Github gist, ...)?  I'm interested in seeing if this problem is easily solvable, or if not, could it be used as the basis  for a language change request.

Comment: I cannot publish it in full right now (it's for a university project) but when (if :D) I pass I will gladly upload it.

Comment: @Master_T -- Just a reminder that we'd like to see your DSA program if/when it's finished.

Comment: @Shark8: sorry for being very late to answer this :D But in the end I ditched DSA and implemented my own RPC-esque protocol using SOAP. Ugly, but DSA was driving me insane, to this day I have little idea of how it operates

Comment: @Master_T -- I know what you mean, GNAT's implementation of the DSA is a little on the clunky-side (I suspect due to it being relatively unused by the hobbyist). -- But I think I'd still like to see the source if you have it up on github or something.